# Simple tutorial on how to create java web service and deploy to mac web server?

Tags: java, macos, post, deployment, service

I'm relatively new to services in java (coming from a C# background) and have been struggling to make sense of it all. I was wondering if someone could help me

1. Create a simple web service with a single method which takes in a string passed in the POST body (representing the contents of a fairly large text file) and returns a transformed version of that string.
2. Deploy said service to a mac web server.

Anything simple, easy to follow, and functional would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [dropwizard](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/)

You can build a simple example following their documentation.

It has everything you need to create a simple REST service:

Jetty (Embedded application server)
Jackson (Java objects - Json)
Jersey (implementation for building web services)

Answer (score 0):

Hope [Web Service Tutorial with Axis](http://www.digizol.com/2008/07/web-service-axis-tutorial-client-server.html) will help you.